# Rescue_from is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rescue

I was trying to handle routing error when I'm loading images and some are missing.

You know I wanted just to replace a missing image with the default image icon and to suppress error message.

So I tried

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
       [...]

       def index
         images = Image.all
         rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :image_route_error
       end

      [...]
 end
```

Then I got this:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `rescue_from' for #<ImagesController:0x007fe382227e38>
Did you mean?  rescue_handlers):
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **rescue_from** any kind of exceptions other than server errors using `rescue_from` method. You write this method in your `ApplicationController`.

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError do |exception|
    if controller_name == "image" && action_name == "index"
           render 'default_image_here', status: 200 
    else
     render plain: 'Not found', status: 400 
   end
end
```

In `render 'default_image_here'` you can use this:

```
render :text => open(image_url, "rb").read, status: 200
```

This will read file as binary instead of text.